# Simplifying a function to check if a specific value exists in a `std::set` in C++

Tags: c#, c++, linq

I have written a function in C++ to check if a particular value exists in a `std::set`. Here's the function:

```cpp
bool check_if_any(set<int> &s, int x)
{
    for (int i : s)
        if (i == x)
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

I'm familiar with LINQ in C# where the same function could be written much more succinctly as:

```cs
bool CheckIfAny(Set<int> s, int x)
{
    return s.Any(i => i == x);
}
```

I would like to simplify the C++ function so that it's as short as the C# version.

Could anyone please show me how to refactor the C++ function using what the language has to offer?

Comment: `set<int> s` copy whole collection?

Comment: Take a look at https://cpplinq.codeplex.com

Comment: Not sure if this is what you want, but `return s.find(x) != s.end();` is shorter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general to find whether any of items in collection matches predicate you can use

```
bool check_if_any(set<int> &s, int x)
{
    return std::any_of(s.begin(), s.end(), [&](int v){ return v==x;});
}
```

but in this case

```
return s.find(x) != s.end();
```

would be better in both speed and clarity.

Answer (score 0):

To find exactly that value you can write something like that:

```
bool check_if_any(const std::set<int>& mySet, int x) {
    return mySet.find(x) != mySet.end();
}
```

or if you want that to look even closer to C# and might want to use your own comparator, use C++11 lambda and `std::find_if()` method:

```
bool check_if_any(const std::set<int>& mySet, int x) {
    return (std::find_if(
        mySet.begin(), mySet.end(), 
        [](int y) { return x == y; }
    ) != mySet.end());
}
```

this way you can make your own lambda function to look for specific argument, not just use default comparable. Note that second option will be slower (linear) since it has to go through every object in container and does not use containers persk like BST or hashmaps.